# Ansible - Set content of file based on dictionary key

Tags: jinja2, ansible

Goal : Set the content of a file based on a dictionary value that I retrieve via  FACT.

In other words, I have  dictionary with like:

```
clients:
  client0:
    bar: my stuff
```

I learn the client name from a FACT, I would like to use the client name to index into the dictionary and retrive bar and set as the content of the file.

```
- name: Copy Client File Content
  copy:
    dest="/opt/myfile"
    content=clients[{{client_name}}].bar
    owner=root
    group=root
    mode=0600
    no_log: true
```

Expected Content of File is : my stuff

Comment: What is your expected output here? What should the file content be given your dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    clients:
      client0:
        bar: my stuff
    client_name: client0
  tasks:
    - name: copy client file content
      copy:
        dest: ./myfile.txt
        content: "{{clients[client_name].bar}}"
```

Your issue is that you appear to be trying to perform variable de-referencing outside of a Jinja2 variable substitution; putting everything inside `{{...}}` is what makes this work.